# Token from API Call is undefined, but works in CURL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, curl, cornerstone

I have an API where I do a POST to get a token. The documentation of the API I have followed is from: https://apiexplorer.csod.com/apiconnectorweb/apiexplorer#/info
I have tried the API via curl and it returns a token as intended:
[image]

Now, I try to do exactly the same but via JavaScript. My code:

```
      fetch( proxyUrl + ' https://myCompany.csod.com/services/api/oauth2/token', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=' + key + '&client_secret=' + secret + "&scope=employee:read",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       
    }
}).then((response) =>console.log(response))
.then((data) => console.log(data));
    };
```

This will return a 200 response:

[image]

But I cannot find the token. I have tried to JSON parse the response etc. but it returns "undefined" or an empty {} json object.

Doing a:

```
.then(response => response.json()).then(data => console.log(data))
```

will return the following error at console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0
```

When I try to convert the response to text and console log it out, I get the proxyUrls site.

There is 3 reasons why this fails and not Curl in my mind:

1. I use proxyUrl for CORS in JavaScript that maybe is the cause.
2. I console log  the response/token wrong.
3. The JavaScript code is wrong.

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: 2 and 3. Replace the `.then()`s with `.then(response => response.json()).then(data => console.log(data));`

Comment: Yes, I have tried that but the  console logs "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0". I have updated my post.it seems it gets the data from the proxyUrl and not from the API-call.

Comment: Then it doesn't return JSON data. Do `.then(response => response.text())` instead.

Comment: Interestingly, that returned the proxyURLs information, and that was why the json() didnt work before (the first letter in the proxySite have "T"). The call is according to the console:
proxyUrl%20APIUrl

Comment: ...well yes, that's what you've set as the URL in the fetch call.

Comment: Exactly, the proxyUrl should enable the cors with the added API call:
https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/
Now, it works for other calls but not obviously not this one. :(

Comment: Uh, no. The cors-anywhere separator is `/` instead of a space.

Comment: It was a blank space when I tried to parse the proxyUrl with the API-call, should have know by the escape %20. Now .then(response => response.json()).then(data => console.log(data)); works. Thanks for the help!